# How to merge a partition which is far away from the one I want to merge it with?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I have my disk partitioned  the following way:

[image]

I want to get rid of sda5 by merging it either with sda1 or sda6. I can't do that right now, can I? Because it's not placed next to either sda1 or 6. So how can I do that?

Comment: Did you ever tweak the partitions before or is this your first time? Is the warranty period over?

Answer (score 0):

You can megre sda5 with sda6:

1. Boot a live CD/USB, prefere [partedmagic](http://partedmagic.com/), it has grsync package.
2. Move the contents of sda5 to a **folder** in sda6. Better sync the data of the partition with the **folder** using grsync, and pay ATTENTION at the pop-up help of the "?" at the Basic Options tab of grsync. **Be sure** not to delete the existing contents of sda6!
3. Delete Swap and sda5 partitions.
4. Create a new Swap partition at the end of the disk.
5. Extend sda6 to fill the empty space.

This way you keep the WinRecovery partition, in case you need it.

But if you want a 15GB partition for future test or permanent installs you could skip steps 3,4,5. At the time of the GPartEd-screenshot seems plenty of free space in sda6.